Irish politicians in the British Empire
Looking back over centuries of British rule in Ireland: Has any Irish person ever served as British prime minister, or foreign minister, or General in the Army, or Admiral in the navy, or Governor General of India? Scots have held these positions, but what about the Irish?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)

There  is no Authoritative answer; in general list questions do not have an authoritative answer and are ill suited to H:SE

Please revise title to ask a question

Yes.  Beside the Duke Wellington, the 1st Marquis of Lansdowne was born in Dublin and was PM from 1782-1783.

@MAGolding: However the Duke of Wellington would have been incensed to have been classed as an Irishman. As he himself put it: "Being born in Ireland no more makes one an Irishman than being born in a stable makes one a horse."

The Duke of Wellington was Irish. He served as a British General, Field Marshal and Prime Minister of Britain.
From Wikipedia:

Field Marshal Arthur Wellesley, 1st Duke of Wellington, KG, GCB, GCH, PC, FRS (né Wesley; 1 May 1769 – 14 September 1852) was an Anglo-Irish military officer and statesman who was one of the leading military and political figures in Britain during the late 18th and early 19th centuries, serving twice as Prime Minister of the United Kingdom...Wellesley was born into a Protestant Ascendancy family in Ireland.


Thank you. I was actually looking for Irish Catholics. but Anglo-Irish is also interesting. Any more?

You should have said so in your question.  There were none before 1829 because Catholics were barred from entering Parliament or holding high office. Lord Castlereagh was also a Protestant.
